# Subtract elements from one list from another list, using list comprehension. Returns incomplete list?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, list-comprehension, notin

I have an array *l1* of size (81x2), and another *l2* of size (8x2). All elements of *l2* are also contained in *l1*. I'm trying to generate an array *l3* of size (73x2) containing all elements of *l1* minus the ones in *l2* ( ==> *l3 = l1 - l2* ), but using list comprehension.

I found many similar questions on here, and almost all agree on a solution like this to generate *l3*:

```
n = 9    
index = np.arange(n)   
 
l1 = np.array([(i,j) for i in index for j in index])
l2 = np.array([(0, 3),(0, 5),(2, 4),(4, 4),(4, 2),(4, 6),(8, 3),(8, 5)])
l3 = [(i,j) for (i,j) in l1 if (i,j) not in l2]

print(l3)
```

However, the code above generates an array *l3* that only contains 20 of the expected (81-8=) 73 elements. I don't understand how list comprehension operates here or why only those particular 20 elements are kept. Can anyone help?

**NOTE:** *many people advise using set() instead of list comprehension for this problem, but I haven't tried that yet and I'd really like to understand why list comprehension is failing in the code above.*

Comment: Are the elements in each unique? If so `np.array(list(set(zip(*l1.T.tolist())).difference(zip(*l2.T.tolist()))))`

Answer (score 0):

Let's test the first row of `l1`:

```
In [46]: i,j = l1[0]
In [47]: i,j
Out[47]: (0, 0)
In [48]: (i,j) in l2
Out[48]: True
```

It's True because `0` occurs in `l2`.  It isn't testing by rows.

There isn't a `7` in `l2`, so this is False

```
In [49]: (7,7) in l2
Out[49]: False
```

Make sure your list comprehension test works.

One way to test for matches is:

```
In [72]: x = (l1==l2[:,None,:]).all(axis=2).any(axis=0)
In [73]: x
Out[73]: 
array([False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False])
```

This has 8 True values, the ones that exactly match `l2`:

```
In [74]: x.sum()
Out[74]: 8
In [75]: l1[x]
Out[75]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [0, 5],
       [2, 4],
       [4, 2],
       [4, 4],
       [4, 6],
       [8, 3],
       [8, 5]])
```

So the rest would be accessed with:

```
In [76]: l1[~x]
```

TO work with sets, we need to convert the arrays to lists of tuples

```
In [85]: s1 = set([tuple(x) for x in l1])
In [86]: s2 = set([tuple(x) for x in l2])
In [87]: len(s1.difference(s2))
Out[87]: 73
```

Another approach is to convert the arrays to structured arrays:

```
In [88]: import np.lib.recfunctions as rf
In [102]: r1 = rf.unstructured_to_structured(l1,dtype=np.dtype('i,i'))
In [103]: r2 = rf.unstructured_to_structured(l2,dtype=np.dtype('i,i'))
In [104]: r2
Out[104]: 
array([(0, 3), (0, 5), (2, 4), (4, 4), (4, 2), (4, 6), (8, 3), (8, 5)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Now `isin` works - the arrays are both 1d, as required by `isin`:

```
In [105]: np.isin(r1,r2)
Out[105]: 
array([False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
       ...])
```

Comment: I couldn't have asked for a more complete answer, thank you!

Comment: I just have a question about this line: In [72]: x = (l1==l2[:,None,:]).all(axis=2).any(axis=0). How come l2 suddenly has 3 dimensions instead of 2?